# Check for errors in a script command

Tags: linux, bash, shell

How do I check for an error in a command before I run it, for example, if i wanted to run an iptables command, but say someone input something wrong into the variable of the script I made, for example "asdiojaosdi" for the $port variable, and when the script tries to plug that into the iptables command, it returns an error, I want it to echo "Error"

I want syntax to check this HUGE command

```
    iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d $filip --dport $port -j DNAT --to-destination $cusip && iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT && iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -d $cusip -j SNAT --to-source $secip && iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j SNAT --to-source $filip
```

Comment: Some commands have a dry run option. You want something that works for ALL commands or just `iptables`?

Comment: Hmm, what if there were a universal interface for all commands to test the validity of their inputs? It would be like … Haskell. For better or worse, given the rich variety of commands in the programmable universe, there is no universal solution to do this without the risk of side effects.

Comment: I'd like something that works for EVERYTHING

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In IXish environments, programs commonly return a value different from `0` in case of failure. Error messages are expected to be logged to standard error, which can be captured via redirecting file descriptor `2`.

You can test for this like so:

```
#!/bin/bash

program option1 option2 2>error.log.$$
result=$? 
if [ $result -ne 0 ]; then
  echo program failed with result=$result: $(cat error.log.$$)
  rm error.log.$$
fi
```

Comment: And then the question becomes 'did the failed attempt to run the command do any damage', and the answer should be "No", but if it isn't, then you have a problem.  And its particularly problematic if the command did as much as it could and committed the changes that were OK.  Sometimes, you can make a copy of the operational config file, and try applying the changes to the copy, and if that works, run the changes on the live system.  It varies between commands, though — and depends on the scope of the command.

Comment: To add to Jonathan's comment: Writing robust and save code implies more than just checking the outcome of any function. If a program/function is parameterised (which obviously often is the case) an essential task is to add as much validation of the input/the arguments passed as possible and only if this validation is passed successfully call the program/function('s body).

Comment: Thanks for this answer, What would the syntax be for that script if i wanted to run an iptables command, like an iptables -t nat -A how would I write a script  to include that.

Comment: @KaveenK: Why not just just replace `program` and `option?` by your program's name and options?

Comment: WHen I plugged this code in, it said unrecognized command, However, i had a ton of iptables syntax.
What would the syntax be if i wanted to have thse iptables:

Comment: @KaveenK: For debugging purpose add to the script `set -x` right after the first line.

Comment: @KaveenK: Also please note that the "command" you added to your question actually is three commands concatenated by the `&&`operator. Better separate them.

Comment: Hello, I get this returned: ./redirect.sh: line 50: [: $: integer expression expected
line 50 is the start of that syntax you gave me.

Comment: What is in line 49? @KaveenK

Comment: I've fixed it, actually I forgot the ? after the $, Thanks for all the help, I got the script working!